# Procedure or function 'Registration_proc1' expects parameter '@p_fullname', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

```
private static Registration InsertData(Registration register)
    {
        string connstr = @"Data Source=JUZAR-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Dbsaif;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Application Name=EntityFramework";

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Registration_proc1", con))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"p_fullname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = register.FullName;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"p_email", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = register.Email;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"p_password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = register.Password;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"p_cfnpswd", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = register.ConfirmPassword;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"p_city", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = register.City;

                    da.SelectCommand = cmd;

                    con.Open();
                    da.Fill(dt);
                    con.Close();

                }
            }
        }
        if (dt != null && dt.Rows != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            register = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
                        select new Registration()
                        {
                            FullName = dr["Name"].ToString(),
                            Email = dr["Email"].ToString(),
                            Password = dr["Password"].ToString(),
                            ConfirmPassword = dr["ConfirmPassword"].ToString(),
                            City = dr["City"].ToString()
                        }).ToList().FirstOrDefault();


        }
        return register;
    }
```

STORED PROCEDURE FOR THE ABOVE CODE IS:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Registration_proc1]     
@p_fullname varchar(50),
@p_email varchar(50),
@p_password varchar(8),
@p_cfnpswd varchar(8),
@p_city varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN       
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
                Insert into Registeration(Name,Email,Password,ConfirmPassword,City)   
           Values (@p_fullname,@p_email,@p_password,@p_cfnpswd,@p_city)  
END
```

Help me with this please:

1.It is throwing an exception on stored proc parameter p_fullname in C# code.

2.And usually I get this error please help me know where am I going wrong.

3.Mostly faced this error while using SQL Server

Comment: Please add the stored procedure's parameter declarations

Comment: Stored Procedure is expecting to pass the @p_fullname parameter while calling it. You have not passed this parameter from your c# code, therefore, you are getting the error. You need to ensure all the parameters which are required  by the procedure should be password from c# code.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the stored procedure in question, I would say that this line here:

```
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"p_name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = register.FullName;
```

should be

```
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"p_fullname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = register.FullName;
```

Just as the exception states. It's expecting THAT parameter and you are not sending it.